# Decoding Color Information from Base64 encoded image ,using java

Tags: java, image, base64

I have a Base64 encoded string of an image. I need to obtain the color information from it. The images are monochromatic red,green.orange.

Kindly help me in this regard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decode it using following code

```
BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
byte[] decodedBytes = decoder.decodeBuffer(encodedBytes);
```

use `decodeBytes` to analyze the pixel data